# Google vision unable to convert "image path" to an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

Google vision is throwing me the following error on ruby on rails which had me baffled.

**Unable to convert "image_path" to an Image**

However, I am able to display each image form it's respective path if I use the image_tag method for rails. Please advise as I am new to this, thank you.

```
<% @uploads.each do |u| %>
<% require "google/cloud/vision"
   vision = Google::Cloud::Vision.new(
   project: "first-ocr-project",
   keyfile: JSON.parse(ENV['GOOGLECLOUD_API_KEY'])
   )

   #Error Unable to convert "image_path" to an Image
   raw_data = vision.image(u.photos[0])
%>

#Able to displays all photos from path
<%= image_tag u.photos[0] %></br>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you checked what input google requires for doing OCR. Because mostly it takes content instead of direct images.

Comment: You need to pass the specific filepath as in [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ruby-docs-samples/blob/master/vision/quickstart.rb#L26). I would recommend to add some logging to see what does `u.photos[0]` contain.

Answer (score 0):

This means that `u.photos[0]` doesn't exist in the path you mentioned. The file may not be available for various reasons.